# WebApi and jQuery getting error status 0

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

I am getting error 0 , when i call a webapi endpoint from jQuery by inputting some invalid characters to the param1 parameter. The same test when done using Swagger, i am getting 400 error. How to respond a uniform response? fyi, i am inputting some rubbish data to param1 i.e *12345

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(string param1)
{
    return Ok();
}

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
           // xhr.status = 0
           // error = ""

        }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: what code is in your webapi endpoint?

Comment: Just a basic functionality to write to database.

Comment: can you show what your endpoint is responding with?

Comment: return Created(new Uri(Request.RequestUri.ToString()), param1);